# AES - Is it sensitive to let anyone encrypt a message only you can decrypt?

Tags: aes

I have an application in which some data can be encrypted through AES.
Such data can emanate from multiple sources I may not know.
For practical reasons I want those sources to be able to encrypt values themselves, without being able to decrypt them later on (only my application would be).

I was wondering whether letting people potentially encrypt messages themselves could expose a weakness.

Should I worry about that?
Should I only encrypt values myself or can I leave a public encryption endpoint exposed?

> Note: the AES cipher is a constraint I have to work with, I can not change algorithm for now.

> Edit: the application is some sort of proxy, in which a user can grant access to his account to other persons, without them actually knowing that account credentials.
>
> - A wants to share an account for the service S with his friends B and C
> - A, B and C create an account on the application
> - A enters his S credentials
> - A grants B and C access to the service S
> - B and C can *use* the service S *through* the application
> - B and C *can not* see the credentials of A
>
> The important part I might have forgot to expose is that A can provide a configuration file containing multiple accounts (to avoid typing manually again when exporting the configuration), on which the credentials has to be encrypted.
> This means A needs to access an encryption service somehow, which I thought providing it through an API might be unsafe (I feel like one might be able to bruteforce in order to find passphrase at some point since they could try the same text with expected results until they find the correct one?).

Comment: I know AES is something you cannot change, but this *screams* for asymmetric encryption.

Comment: By definition, the source know the data (they are the source), so not being able to decrypt it is a moot point. This requirement only makes sense if the point is that Source A should not decrypt data from Source B.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you edit your answer to explain *why* people need to encrypt values themselves, and why it has to be with AES (and not e.g. using asymmetric encryption)? Also, what do you mean by "public encryption endpoint"? What is that supposed to be?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MechMK1 I would have done that if I could indeed, the need of AES comes from the fact that the application manager does not want to handle multiple public/private key per "customer" (account).

Comment: @ThoriumBR that is exactly it, I explained more in details in the edit. A can place a value he wants to hide from B, while B can still consume the value without knowing it himself (the application knows it tho).

Comment: @sleske sorry, it is hard to explain my case without going too much into details since I do not know much about security policies and where is the point where I give too much information about my application. I edited hoping the example would give a better idea of the problem.

Comment: It looks way more an authentication/authorization question than encryption. Your users aren't encrypting nor decrypting anything, your service is. Users are using the service, and the service is encrypting, decrypting, and granting access as needed.

Comment: They are encrypting in the case they want to provide a configuration file with already encrypted data.

Comment: You don't need to provide any configuration file with encrypted data if the user isn't encrypting anything. It can have a token, and the server will use the token to authorize access, but the token isn't the encryption key.

Comment: @VincentC. You don't need any key pairs per customer. All you need is one public key for your endpoint, allowing everyone to encrypt data for you. This seems more like the application owner doesn't understand what cryptography is appropriate for what task.

Comment: @MechMK1 you are definitely right, but I have no power to change this as of today. So I just wonder whether providing an encryption endpoint to the public is a security flaw. I think it is, but am I not a security expert.

Comment: @ThoriumBR sorry for my poor english, but the user can either type credentials manually or provide a configuration file. In such cases, if he chooses to initialize using the configuration file, he needs to provide directly an encrypted value of the credentials (for obvious security reasons). That is the functional case the application owner wants to solve using an encryption endpoint (and I am pretty sure it is a security flaw).

Comment: UserA should not send his credentials to anyone. UserA should access the "shares management area" on his account and grant UserB access to that resource. When UserB access the system, he would have a list of all resources he can access. The way you described, this system have lots of loose things badly integrated.

Comment: UserB does not access the configuration file nor can he sees the credentials in a back office nor anywhere else. My whole point is that UserA should be able to forge a file in which he can tells whether a parameter is encrypted or not. If it is, it does not appear for UserB. But anyway, UserA would need to encrypt it at some point, and the whole question is how to do so without creating a flaw?

Comment: Sorry to insist and sound stubborn, but if we forget the functional case, is letting authorized user encrypt their own value with my own passphrase is a security flaw? Should I rephrase the question to simplify it as such?

Comment: @VincentC. Yes, letting another user access your private passphrase is a security issue. Other security issues are also present in the process you described.

Comment: What do you mean "access your private passphrase"? They will only access an endpoint taking a value to encrypt, encrypt it and return the encrypted value. They would _never_ see the private passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand all your issues here, however here are my thoughts on the matter:

- Do not use a hammer to screw screws, even if that's tempting when you only have a hammer. Go fetch a screwdriver instead.
- Be sure that you indeed have a screw in front of you before going to fetch the screwdriver.
- Here, that means using proper authentication and access control, and not touching encryption.
- If indeed you need encryption because I misunderstood your issues, please use asymmetric encryption (using TLS, and nothing else), not just AES. (You can still pick a TLS ciphersuite with AES to please your product owner.)
- Proper authentication implies that credentials (and encryption keys) remains secret.
- Proper authorization means that A can gives access to B, then B can use this now authorized access using its own credentials without needing to use A's credentials.
- If you need to protect communications (authentication, confidentiality, integrity), just use the proven TLS 1.3 protocol. Libraries already exists for it. Do not build your own protocol, because by experience your are almost sure to make mistakes on issues you were not aware of.
- Please avoid using AES directly. Many obscure pitfalls exists when using it. It is very hard to use it correctly. Use TLS, or ask a cryptographer for a review of your encryption scheme beforehand.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why AES is hard to use correctly? What obscure pitfalls?

Comment: @8vtwo Just ask your comment as a new question.

Comment: @8vtwo But short answer is that people tend to mess up pretty much everything they possible can. One example: reusing the same IV for different encryptions in CBC mode.

Comment: @hft Why ask a question? I didn't have a question about AES, my question was about what you consider to be pitfalls. The purpose of an IV is not a mystery.

Comment: You literally asked a question about AES: "Could you elaborate on why AES is hard to use correctly?"

Comment: @8vtwo encryption is hard to use correctly. You're either an expert that can do it without asking StackOverflow for help, or you aren't and StackOverflow won't be much help.

Comment: @hft My question was regarding your opinion, not about AES itself.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Fallacious opinion: "You can either do it without learning, or you can't ever learn"

Comment: @8vtwo If you are not an expert, you can learn to become one, it will take time and effort, and StackOverflow won't be much help.

Comment: @8vtwo take a look at the amount of problematic security decisions on top StackOverflow answers. There's even a paper on the quality of those answers, and the outlook isn't pretty.